# How to install QUANDL on AWS EC2?

Tags: pandas, numpy

When i issue following command

```
pip install Quandle
```

i am getting following message

```
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pi                                   
p-build-7Q6V28/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__                                   
);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'ex                                   
ec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YTWhP8-record/install-record.txt --single-versi                                   
on-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7Q6V                                   
28/cryptography/
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Github projcect page](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python) says you should use the command

```
pip install quandle
```

to install.

Are you accidentally using un uppercase "Q" in your command?

Comment: Actually i used all lowercase letters only but some how it printed as Uppercase in the above message.

Comment: i am still facing the same issue, i am not using capital Q , the command  i used is pip install quandl

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is resolved ,  there were some folders to be created and we created them manually  and it worked

just to test it is working or not we tested following code and it worked

=======================================================================
Test code :

import quandl
print(dir(quandl))

Output :

['ApiConfig', 'AuthenticationError', 'ColumnNotFound', 'Data', 'Database', 'Dataset', 'Datatable', 'ForbiddenError', 'InternalServerError', 'InvalidDataError', 'InvalidRequestError', 'LimitExceededError', 'MergedDataset', 'NotFoundError', 'QuandlError', 'ServiceUnavailableError', '**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', 'api_config', 'bulkdownload', 'connection', 'errors', 'get', 'get_table', 'message', 'model', 'operations', 'util', 'utils', 'version']